Normalize and model relationships between report data and survey responses
Background:
I have scenario with two data sets;

Contains company data collected from a reporting system, let's call it $ReportingData$, with numeral features for instance hours_worked, meeting_hours, collaboration_hours, company_role, seniority, ... and so forth.

The same individuals, have in a survey responded to questions through a rating between 0-5 to questions such as wellbeing, workplace_experience, .... Let's call this $SurveyData$.


What I want to do:
I wish to examine how/if the different features in $ReportingData$ can provide insights on how people respond in the $SurveyData$. That is, how does the different features contribute to for instance wellbeing. I'm hoping that this will be able to provide guidance on what to improve in the workplace eg., "we can see that the most important factor influencing wellbeing is hours_worked, contributing 20% of the overall wellbeing and thus we should focus on reducing the number of hours worked if we want to improve wellbeing".
Questions:

As my data contains grouped data from all different roles and seniorities, I think it's important to regard that across the company expectations and roles look very different. Someone working in department $x$ might be working "a lot" if they work 60 hours a week, whereas someone working in department $y$ might be working a lot if they work 44 hours a week. One approach I've considered is using Z-scores as a way to normalize my data based on the different seniority and role. Do you have any feedback on this or if I should try a different approach?

Do you have any modelling recommendations or perhaps a family of models that would be suitable for the output I'm trying to produce? I've played around with regression models and percentage relative importance as a metric to evaluate.



There are various methodological problems with the design of employee engagement surveys, which should be your main concern before any attempt at analyzing the data. I address that at the end of this answer, but to give you some very general pointers about the questions you asked:

As my data contains grouped data from all different roles and
seniorities, I think it's important to regard that across the company
expectations and roles look very different.
Someone working in department $x$ might be working "a lot" if they work
60 hours a week, whereas someone working in department $y$ might be
working a lot if they work 44 hours a week. [...]

Using an interaction term department:hours worked in a regression model might address the issue. Alternatively, treating "department" as a random effect in a mixed model may be more adequate. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/151800/164936 for some discussion and details.

I wish to examine how/if the different features in $ReportingData$ can
provide insights on how people respond in the $SurveyData$. That is, how
does the different features contribute to for instance wellbeing. [...]
Do you have any modelling recommendations or perhaps a family of
models that would be suitable for the output I'm trying to produce?

If well-being is measured by a single question on an ordinal scale, then an ordinal regression model may be relevant. However, if well-being it measured by multiple questions, then you could construct some sort of composite index from these questions, and use this index as an outcome variable. How to construct this kind of index is a statistical question but also a domain-specific one (e.g. psychology, sociology of work and organizations, etc.). Therefore you should refer to studies using similar indices about workplace well-being, to determine how to construct such an index, and what kind of model to use to analyze it.
Apart from that, an additional thing you should watch for is how many variables you could include in your model, given the sample size you have.

The same individuals, have in a survey responded to questions through
a rating between 0-5 to questions such as wellbeing,
workplace_experience, ....

It sounds like that the survey was not anonymous, given that you can match two different datasets about the employees. I guess you're already aware of that, but if the survey is indeed not anonymous, this has almost certainly biased the truthfulness of the answers in favor of positive answers. Even supposedly anonymous engagement surveys may have this kind of issue. This can make it very hard to make a relevant analysis of the data. There is a plethora of academic articles  or articles for the general public discussing the methodological pitfalls of employee engagement surveys, that you could find quite informative if you're not already familiar with that.
